# VB.net 'textbox1 is not declared' as it is created during module/form load

Tags: vb.net, variables

I am using VB.net, Programming a Visual Basic Application.
I decided to, instead of using the user interface to drag and drop the elements onto my form, I programmed it, I have added events for some of these buttons which refer to multiple textboxes that are created alongside the buttons in a module, Once the module has created them, it runs the form.

So far so good, the moment I include the events, that refer to not yet existing but surely will existing textboxes, it refuses to run the code.

Any help appreciated thanks.

This is the code creating the elements and refering to the Event.
It refers to the event as such 'AddHandler btnArray(n).Click, AddressOf SetupWindow.OK_Click' which is the only piece relevant, I included the lot for testing only.

```
If SetupID = "SimpleArray" Then
    Dim btnArray(1) As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    For i As Integer = 0 To btnArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Next i
    For n = 0 To btnArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        With (btnArray(n))
            ' Location of button:            .Left = xPos
            ' Add buttons to a Panel:            
            SetupWindow.Controls.Add(btnArray(n)) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
            btnArray(n).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            If n = 0 Then
                .Width = 55 ' Width of button
                .Height = 30 ' Height of button
                .Text = "OK"
                .Top = 325
                .Left = 175
                AddHandler btnArray(n).Click, AddressOf SetupWindow.OK_Click
            End If
            If n = 1 Then
                .Width = 55 ' Width of button
                .Height = 30 ' Height of button
                .Text = "Cancel"
                .Top = 325
                .Left = 50
                AddHandler btnArray(n).Click, AddressOf SetupWindow.Cancel_Click
            End If
            '.Text = Alphabet(n)
        End With
    Next

    Dim Combobox1 As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Combobox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(Combobox1) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    Combobox1.Width = 140 ' Width of button
    Combobox1.Height = 25 ' Height of button
    Combobox1.Top = 20
    Combobox1.Left = 16
    Combobox1.Items.Add("Write To The End Of File")
    Combobox1.Items.Add("Write to Current Location")
    Combobox1.Items.Add("Smart Wizard")
    Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    '.Text = Alphabet(n)

    Dim TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(TextBox1) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    TextBox1.Width = 120 ' Width of button
    TextBox1.Height = 25 ' Height of button
    TextBox1.Top = 60
    TextBox1.Left = 125

    Dim Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(Label1) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    Label1.Width = 80
    Label1.Height = 25
    Label1.Top = 60
    Label1.Left = 16
    Label1.Text = "Constant"

    Dim TextBox2 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    TextBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(TextBox2) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    TextBox2.Width = 120
    TextBox2.Height = 25
    TextBox2.Top = 100
    TextBox2.Left = 125

    Dim Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(Label2) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    Label2.Width = 80
    Label2.Height = 25
    Label2.Top = 100
    Label2.Left = 16
    Label2.Text = "Equation"

    Dim RichTextBox3 As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    RichTextBox3 = New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(RichTextBox3) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    RichTextBox3.Width = 120
    RichTextBox3.Height = 80
    RichTextBox3.Top = 140
    RichTextBox3.Left = 125

    Dim Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(Label3) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    Label3.Width = 80
    Label3.Height = 25
    Label3.Top = 140
    Label3.Left = 16
    Label3.Text = "Initial Values"

    Dim TextBox4 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    TextBox4 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(TextBox4) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    TextBox4.Width = 50 ' Width of button
    TextBox4.Height = 25 ' Height of button
    TextBox4.Top = 240
    TextBox4.Left = 125

    Dim Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
    SetupWindow.Controls.Add(Label4) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
    Label4.Width = 120
    Label4.Height = 25
    Label4.Top = 240
    Label4.Left = 16
    Label4.Text = "Number Of Attempts"

    SetupWindow.ShowDialog()
End If
```

The event is stored on the form and has all the elements marked red as they are not yet created...which would be perfectly fine as long as I could run it but with vb, I can only run the last build.

```
Public Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    HandleSimpleArray(textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text, textbox4.text)
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you associating the events?

Comment: You need to provide some code

Comment: Have you tried [add and remove handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: From what I understan I am using addhandler, Edited original post for more detail

Comment: What is the supposed advantage to writing all that rather than using the designer?

Comment: As @Plutonix said, why not just use the designer? It's a lot more straight-forward than hard coding form designs

Comment: The approach meant to be so that instead of having hundreds of similar forms, have a few, wich are setup differently each time based on code.

Comment: I have done something similar in the past. You need to make sure that your control names have enough scope to be seen by your method. I would declare them with class scope, and then new them up as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved if the maximum number of textboxes , buttons, etc. are met on the form, and deleting them in code, replacing them with the coded Elements, but that is just a waste of time, might as well use the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you invert the order and create the textboxes before the AddHandler instruction it can be solved.

I'm not sure but if the runtime check the created event before the textboxes, is the only reason to refuse to run with the pointed message (Textboxes not found).

I would suggest also to create all controls in the LOAD (or even NEW) events of the SETUP form. I don't see why create them in a module or another form.

Try it... Good luck.